# Search in associative array by key

Tags: arrays, search, search-tree

I have a set of numbers where each number has a key (ex. {"key1":1, "key2":2}). All the keys are unique. What is the best data structure to store them such that I can search by a key and find the value of that key efficiently? (possibly in logN time)

Comment: An associative array like you're using gives you O(1) lookup, so you're done.

Comment: The usual data structure is a hash table. Under reasonable assumptions, its performance is O(1) for all operations.